# Real Analysis Definitions and Practice

Tags: real-analysis, definition, examples-counterexamples

I am learning real analysis currently and when I am given definitions I like to find examples of the definitions so that I can have them in my "toolbox". Thus, I am looking for a few examples of things. I am also open to leaving any sort of practice involving definitions. If this sort of post is not allowed here please help send it to the right area. Thanks.

> Example of something that is NOT an open cover
>
> Example of finite subcover
>
> Example of something that is/is not uniformly continuous (I have a few of these but don't have concept entirely grasped)
>
> Using the Squeeze Theorem
>
> Mesh/Norm (Are these the same thing?)
>
> Is topology an entire subject or can there be an example of a topology? I was given guidelines of one but I've never seen just a topology?

Comment: All 6 of your questions could be good on this site if you add context: what book/definitions are you using? What were your thoughts/what are you unsure of? Have you googled for answers? (If so, is there something you don't understand on some page?)

Comment: Hello @MarkS. I am using Elementary Analysis: The Theory of Calculus by Kenneth A Ross. I generally understand the definitions but I'm just looking for specific examples of these terms. I have found that mesh and norm are the same thing. I've found a few examples on the internet but am looking for a few more.